# Warning (10631): VHDL Process Statement warning: inferring latch(es) for signal or variable

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm trying learning to code in VHDL and the below code gives me no errors when compiling but gives me a latching warning. I need to get rid of this latch as I believe it is causing me problems in my next piece of code which will use this (8x8 multiplier).

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY control IS
    PORT (
        clk, reset_a, start : IN STD_LOGIC;
        count : IN UNSIGNED (1 DOWNTO 0);
        input_sel, shift_sel : OUT UNSIGNED(1 DOWNTO 0);
        state_out : OUT UNSIGNED(2 DOWNTO 0);
        done, clk_ena, sclr_n : OUT STD_LOGIC
        );

END ENTITY control;

ARCHITECTURE logic OF control IS

    type logic_state is (idle, lsb, mid, msb, calc_done, err);

    signal current_state: logic_state;
    signal next_state: logic_state;

BEGIN
    PROCESS (clk, reset_a)
    BEGIN
        if reset_a = '1' then
            current_state <= idle;
        elsif rising_edge (clk) then
            current_state <= next_state;
        end if;
    END PROCESS;

    PROCESS (current_state, start, count)
    BEGIN

    CASE current_state IS
        when idle =>
        if start = '1' then
            next_state <= lsb;
        else
            next_state <= idle;
        end if;

        when lsb =>
        if start = '0' and count = "00" then
            next_state <= mid;
        else
            next_state <= err;
        end if;

        when mid =>
        if start = '0' then
            if (count = "01") then
                next_state <= mid;
            elsif (count = "10") then
                next_state <= msb;
            else
                next_state <= err;
            end if;
        end if;

        when msb =>
        if start = '0' then
            if (count = "11") then
                next_state <= calc_done;
            else
                next_state <= err;
            end if;
        end if;

        when calc_done =>
        if start = '0' then
            next_state <= idle;
        else
            next_state <= err;
        end if;

        when err =>
        if start = '1' then
            next_state <= lsb;
        else
            next_state <= err;
        end if;

    END CASE;
    END PROCESS;

    mealy: PROCESS (current_state, start, count) 
    BEGIN     
        input_sel <= "00";
        shift_sel <= "00";
        done <= '0';
        clk_ena <= '0';
        sclr_n <= '1';

    CASE current_state IS
        when idle =>
        if start = '1' then
            sclr_n <= '0';
            clk_ena <= '1';
        END IF;

        when lsb =>
        if start = '0' and count = "00" then
            sclr_n <= '1';                                                                       
        end if;

        when mid =>
        if start = '0' then
            if (count = "01") then
                input_sel <= "01";
                shift_sel <= "01";
            elsif (count = "10") then
                input_sel <= "10";
                shift_sel <= "01";
            end if;
        end if;

        when msb =>
        if start = '0' then
            if (count = "11") then
                input_sel <= "11";
                shift_sel <= "10";
            end if;
        end if;

        when calc_done =>
        if start = '0' then
            input_sel <= "00";
            shift_sel <= "00";
            done <= '1';
            clk_ena <= '0';
        end if;

        when err =>
        if start = '1' then
            input_sel <= "00";
            shift_sel <= "00";
            done <= '0';
            clk_ena <= '1';
            sclr_n <= '0';
        end if;

    END CASE;
    END PROCESS mealy;

    moore: PROCESS(current_state)
    BEGIN
        state_out <= "000";

    CASE current_state IS
        WHEN idle =>

        WHEN lsb =>
            state_out <= "001";

        WHEN mid =>
            state_out <= "010";

        WHEN msb =>
            state_out <= "011";

        WHEN calc_done =>
            state_out <= "100";

        WHEN err =>
            state_out <= "101";

    END CASE;
    END PROCESS moore;
END ARCHITECTURE logic;
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning (10631): VHDL Process Statement warning at mult_control.vhd(65): inferring latch(es) for signal
or variable "next_state", which holds its previous value in one or more paths through the process
```

That points to this node (line 33):

```
    PROCESS (current_state, start, count)
```

And that warning leads to other warnings (for every type .idle, .mid, .msb, etc.):

```
Warning (13012): Latch next_state.idle_218 has unsafe behavior
    Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal start
```

Thank you!

Comment: The withdrawn IEEE Std 1076.6 RTL Synthesis standard explains how latches are inferred - 6.2.1.1 Level-sensitive storage from process with sensitivity list
"A level-sensitive storage element shall be modeled for a signal (or variable) when all the following apply: a) The signal (or variable) has an explicit assignment. b) The signal (or variable) does not have an execution path with <clock_edge> as a condition. c) There are executions of the process that do not execute an explicit assignment (via an assignment statement) to the signal (or variable)."

Comment: That said the risk of inferred latches comes mainly when more than one condition contributes to a latch enable. Difference in routing, fan out and rise and fall times can produce enable glitches. It's less likely  your sequential state machine implemented multiplier would suffer from the added propagation delay through an enabled latch.

Answer (score 1):

line 33 is in the second process (with no label).

Why are there inferred latches?

See IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (withdrawn) RTL Synthesis
6.2.1.1 Level-sensitive storage from process with sensitivity list

> A level-sensitive storage element shall be modeled for a signal (or variable) when all the following apply:
>
> > a) The signal (or variable) has an explicit assignment.
> >     b) The signal (or variable) does not have an execution path with  as a condition.
> >     c) There are executions of the process that do not execute an explicit assignment (via an assignment statement) to the signal (or variable).
>
> By default, the effect of an identity assignment of the signal (or variable) shall be as though the assignment was not present.
>   If the combinational attribute decorates the signal (or variable), combinational logic with feedback shall be synthesized.

To avoid unintentional latches as condition c) has to be invalid.

An example in the question code that can cause latches:

```vhdl
        when msb =>
        if start = '0' then
            if (count = "11") then
                next_state <= calc_done;
            else
                next_state <= err;
            end if;
        end if;
```

This is missing an else for the outer if statement and meets rule c) quoted above. That can be cured:

```vhdl
        when msb =>
        if start = '0' then
            if (count = "11") then
                next_state <= calc_done;
            else
                next_state <= err;
            end if;
        else  -- now all binary values of start in state msb assign next_state
            next_state <= msb;
        end if;
```

You can assign a value to a target before an if statement that otherwise meets c):

```vhdl
        when msb =>
        next_state <= msb;  -- not always assigned in the if statement
        if start = '0' then
            if (count = "11") then
                next_state <= calc_done;
            else
                next_state <= err;
            end if;
        end if;
```

In a sequence of statements the 'default' assignment occurs unless overwritten by a subsequent assignment in the if statement.

The question's code has other occurrences of c) issues (including in other processes) that can be similarly treated.